# A question based on fields and irreducible polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

This question was asked in my abstract algebra quiz and I couldnot solve it correctly .

> Choose the correct statements from below:

> 1. There exists a subfield $F$ of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $F$ is not contained in $\mathbb{R}$ and $F$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[X] /(2X^{3} -3X^{2}+ 6)$.
> 2. For every irreducible cubic polynomial $f(x)$ belonging to $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, there exists a subfield $F$ of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $F$ is not contained in $\mathbb{R} $ and $F$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[X]/f(X)$.
> 3. There exists a subfield $F$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[X] /(2X^{3}-3X^{2}+6)$ .
> 4. For every irreducible cubic polynomial $f(X)$ belonging to $\mathbb{Q}[X] $, there exists a subfield $F$ of $\mathbb{R} $ such that $F$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[X] /f(X)$.

The problem in this question is due to the reason that I am unable to understand what correlation $\mathbb{Q}[X]  /f(X) $  ($f(X)$ being irreducible) will have with $\mathbb{R} $ or $\mathbb{C} $.

Kindly provide hint for any option, I would like to work out the rest on my own.

Comment: Hin t: Substitute a  root $\alpha$ of $2X^3-3X^2+6$  into the polynomials of $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ (the evaluation homomorphism). How many roots are there? Where do they lie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point here is in "and $F$ is *isomorphic* to".

If $f$ is an irreducible polynomial over ${\mathbb Q}$ and $\alpha \in {\mathbb C}$ is a root of $f$, then the quotient field ${\mathbb Q}[X]/(f)$ is isomorphic to the subfield ${\mathbb Q}(\alpha)$ of ${\mathbb C}$.

So, for 1), you need to show that $2X^3−3X^2+6$ has a root $\alpha \in {\mathbb C}$ that is not in ${\mathbb R}$ (in which case the statement is true) or that all its roots are in ${\mathbb R}$ (in which case the statement is false).